# Why I am getting the error "Server returned HTTP code: 404" using Google App Engine and Google Earth Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a simple program that I can use as a working example for the Google Earth Engine API, however I get the above error whenever I run it. Here is the code:

```
import ee
import ee.mapclient

image1 = ee.Image(1);
print(image1);
```

As you can see it is a very simple program I just want to get it to run so I can do more advanced tasks but I can't even get this simple one to work.

Answer (score 1):

You did not authenticate your application, hence the error.

Add:

```
ee.Initialize()
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I added this line right after the first import statement and had no luck so I tried after the second and still nothing. I get the same error. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user3431573 Let's start from scratch then. Have you followed installation instructions https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install ? How exactly are you running it? Be sure to do python -c "import ee; ee.Initialize()" - don't try do this from e.g. IPython / Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Any idea why `ee.Initialize()` produces error from Jupyter Notebook? @Lukasz Tracewski

Comment: Does it produce the error outside Jupyter? Is it 404?

Comment: Yes, it actually used to give me `EEException` `404` error inside and outside Jupyter Notebook!  And it terns out I have not signed up for Google Earth Engine-- in the first place!

It is now woking inside Jupyter Notebook once I have signed up

Comment: Yes, signing up for the service helps a great deal :). It's an excellent compute engine - have fun! If you have just started, I'd recommend using the "Playground" of GEE instead of Jupyter.